# Angular track object property changes

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I'm retrieving object value from an api service and showing in html element to allow use to make any change in `page` property
It will be two way data binding so, i want to check if there any change detect in `page` property. Here is a scenario.

This is my component:

```
  export class TestComponent implements OnInit{

  page:any = {};
  changesSaved:boolean = false;

  constructor(
    private route:ActivatedRoute
  ) { 
      this.route.params.subscribe(params=>{
        this.currentParam = params.id;
        params.id? this.onGetPageSettings(params.id): false;
      })
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  onGetPageSettings(id){
    this.configureService.getPageSettings(id)
      .subscribe((response:any)=>{
        let pageConfig = response.data;
        this.page.attrib1 =  pageConfig.page_id;
        this.page.attrib2 =  pageConfig.page_name;
        this.page.attrib3 =  pageConfig.page_desc;
      },error=>{
        console.log(error)
      })
  }

}
```

Here is an html code, i'm using ui switch for option change

```
<form role="form">
    <div class="form-body">
        <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
            <label class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 control-label">{{ 'AUTO_LIKE_COMMENT' | translate }}</label>
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
                <ui-switch [checked]="page.page_like_comment" name="page_like_comment" [(ngModel)]="page.page_like_comment"></ui-switch>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">

            <label class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 control-label">{{ 'AUTO_REPLY_COMMENT_WITH_COMMENT' | translate }}</label>
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
                <ui-switch [checked]="page.page_reply_comment" name="page_reply_comment" [(ngModel)]="page.page_reply_comment"></ui-switch>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">

            <label class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 control-label">{{ 'AUTO_REPLY_COMMENT_WITH_PRIVATE_MESSAGE' | translate }}</label>
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
                <ui-switch [checked]="page.page_reply_comment_with_message" name="page_reply_comment_with_message" [(ngModel)]="page.page_reply_comment_with_message"></ui-switch>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">

            <label class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 control-label">{{ 'AUTO_INBOX_MESSAGING' | translate }}</label>
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
                <ui-switch [checked]="page.page_reply_message" name="page_reply_message" [(ngModel)]="page.page_reply_message"></ui-switch>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">

            <label class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 control-label">{{ 'SELF_LEARNING_AI' | translate }}</label>
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
                <ui-switch [checked]="page.include_comment_text_in_message" name="include_comment_text_in_message" [(ngModel)]="page.include_comment_text_in_message"></ui-switch>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
            <label class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 control-label">{{ 'IGNORE_TAG_FRIEND_COMMENT' | translate }}</label>
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
                <ui-switch [checked]="page.ignore_tag_comment" name="ignore_tag_comment" [(ngModel)]="page.ignore_tag_comment"></ui-switch>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group form-md-line-input">

            <label class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 control-label">{{ 'IGNORE_STICKER_COMMENT' | translate }}</label>
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
                <ui-switch [checked]="page.ignore_sticker_comment" name="ignore_sticker_comment" [(ngModel)]="page.ignore_sticker_comment"></ui-switch>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</form>
```

i know ngModelChange will do the job but i want a generic way so that i don't have to apply on every input element.

Like in following html code, i'm also using a custom directive for allowing user to input info in array and then appending this info in `page` property.

```
<div token-field name="comment" [value]="page.page_default_comment" (tokenAdded)="addDefaultComment($event)" heading="Add Comment" addButtonLabel="Add Comment"></div>
```

Comment: You havent mentioned what is the problem you are facing, also you need to add html code.

Comment: If you directly mutate an object through double binding there is no direct way to track the properties changed. You either proxy the object behind another or bind the events of the UI that create those changes to some logic in your component.

Comment: Is there any way i can use property like we use usually use in angular1 "$watch" ?

Comment: @IrfanMuhammad You can use (ngModelChange)="yourFunctionHere()" for detecting model changes

Comment: @CassianoMontanari yes i know ngModelChange will do the job but i want a generic way so that i don't have to apply on every input element.

Comment: @DheerajKumar i have updated question

Comment: Chang you want to detect on view or in data which has come through API call??

Comment: @DheerajKumar i want to detect if user again made any change in data after it reflect on view?

Answer (score 0):

Ideal way would be to store previous values in a var and use NgModel to compare it.

But As you asked for generic way to detec change,

You can use OnChange event in your component.

https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges

Where in `ngOnChanges` method you can write your rule if value of your fields have changed by storing initial values in other variable and comparing it inside `ngOnChanges`()

Additionally you can check this out as well.

https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

Comment: `ChangeDetectorRef` only for manualy  force angular to detect changes not for get changes meta data. also `ngOnChanges` only work on `@Input` and `@Output`, not for every variables.